# Calculating annual return from monthly return, why does it generate Nan?

Tags: r, xts

I have some irregular data below, that gives me the monthly return correctly. Now I wish to transform it into annual geometric return, but for some reason it returns NaN for many values.

I suspect it is because of how the index values in the xts objet is ordered, but I do not know how to turn them into descending (couldn't find an answer to it either online).

What is wrong? And how can it be resolved?

Code below

```
Browse[2]> Data.xts[,1]
           monthly.returns
2012-09-27     -0.02469261
2012-10-30     -0.05129329
2012-11-29      0.05129329
2012-12-30      0.11778304
2013-01-30     -0.14310084
2013-02-27     -0.08004271
2013-03-28     -0.02817088
2013-04-29     -0.02898754
2013-05-30      0.16251893
2013-06-27      0.00000000
2013-07-30      0.52324814
2013-08-29      0.86927677
2013-09-29     -0.01250016
2013-10-30      0.02484600
2013-11-28     -0.06986968
2013-12-30     -0.06453852
2014-01-30      0.17055672
2014-02-27      0.22195942
2014-03-30      0.02342027
2014-04-29     -0.11258822
2014-05-29      0.03061464
2014-06-29     -0.08381867
2014-07-30     -0.06782260
2014-08-28     -0.08541775
2014-09-29     -0.10394609
2014-10-30     -0.29833937
2014-11-27      0.05556985
2014-12-30     -0.22652765

Browse[2]> annualReturn(Data.xts[, 'monthly.returns'] , type = 'log')
           yearly.returns
2012-12-30            NaN
2013-12-30            NaN
2014-12-30       1.255605
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the inner workings of the `annualReturn()` function, whether it be a custom function you wrote or whether it came from some package, but one likely explanation for what you are seeing `NaN` in multiple places is that you are doing some logarithmic function with negative numbers.

Just using base R, we can see that:

```
> log(-2)
[1] NaN
```

Taking the log of a negative number yields `NaN`, and I believe this may be what you are seeing with your data.

Comment: The annualReturn is from the quantmod package. I think the issue is that I'm trying to use the anualReturn on the monthly returns given, and not the monthly Close and Open prices for the stock. It shuold work fine by using the Close and Open prices.

Comment: @uncool This sounds like a good explanation.  At least you verified that you are feeding in negative numbers to `annualReturn`.

Answer (score 2):

The `?annualReturn` *Description* says,

> Given a set of prices, return periodic returns.

So it expects prices and you give it returns, which it treats as prices. And as [Tim Biegeleisen shows in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38439144/271616), taking the log of a negative number results in NaN.

---

You can use `apply.yearly` to aggregate your returns directly, assuming your returns are arithmetic.

```
> apply.yearly(1+x, prod)-1
                  [,1]
2012-12-30  0.08731379
2013-12-30  1.16831187
2014-12-30 -0.46319006
```

If they're log returns, you should sum them.

```
> apply.yearly(x, sum)
                  [,1]
2012-12-30  0.09309043
2013-12-30  1.15267951
2014-12-30 -0.47633945
```